# Display names of HealthKit types

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, translation, healthkit

I was exploring the HealthKit APIs and was surprised not to find a method like `name` on `HKObjectType`, `HKSampleType`, `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier`, or `HKQuantityType`.

Is there not a way in HealthKit to return a localized display name of a quantity like `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryThiamin`, so that 3rd party apps use the same strings to represent types as the Health app does?

For instance, convert the quantity type identified by `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex` to the localized human-readable string `"Body Mass Index"` as Apple does in the Health app.

Should we translate these medical terms ourselves at our own discretion?

Comment: Swift, or Objective C?

Comment: `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryThiamin` appears to be a string. not an enum.  What is in that string?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Nutrition_Identifiers

Comment: The string is the same as the identifier: @"HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryThiamin"

Comment: Is that just a placeholder until you put an amount in there?  I don't really understand their API; it doesn't make much sense to me.  All this crap should be in some sort of database, not baked into the code.

Comment: Are you trying to display the localized quantity of a sample that exists in the HealthKit or some sample you wish to add, but not sure how to save it?

Comment: @goldengil Neither. I'd like to display the localized *name* of a sample *type*. For instance, convert the quantity type identified by `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex` to the string "Body Mass Index" as Apple does in the Health app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, at the moment `HealthKit` (as for iOs 8.0.2) don't have a direct API for such a thing. Basically it is the developer responsibility to localize the name of a sample type as well as the units. (though there are associated tools to localize the units).

Answer (score -1):

At this time there is no API for directly accessing such localized string.

For more information, check out:  http://web.archive.org/web/20141027202247/http://eriphonedeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/a-soft-touch-of-apple-healthkit-healthkit-tutorial/

Comment: link is now dead ☠️

Comment: https://appengineer.in/2014/09/30/a-soft-touch-of-apple-healthkit-healthkit-tutorial/

Comment: I can't see how this article helps? Can you copy and paste the relevant code into SO?